# Header longer than page

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to understand why my page is doing this, but the header is longer than the page. Even if I make the header shorter than 100%, there is still white space that is passed the edge of the page. I have gone through removed parts of code trying to figure out what is causing it, but I really can't figure it out. I'll put the HTML here, but the CSS is too long to include, so I'll also leave the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2qVUg/

```
<body>
<div id="header">
<img src="x" height="66" width="427" id="logo" />
<ul id="unordered">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
    <li><img src="x" height="15px" width="15px" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="body">
<div id="main">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
    <div id="controls"><form action="#" method="POST">Enter a Comment: <br /><textarea sizable="false"></textarea><br /><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><p></p></div>
</body>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your header is longer ... in width, in height?  Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the `padding-left: 80px` on the `#header` it's pushing the header beyond the rest of the content

you can wrap that content in a container and set `margin-left: 80px` if you want

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2qVUg/8/)

Comment: Ah, I see now. That's weird, I thought I tried editing that previously, but it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jmore009 is correct. You can have

```
width:100%;
```

And

```
padding-left: 80px;
```

that makes the header 100% + 80px which isn't possible so it gets pushed out of containment.

Instead, add the padding to your logo image

header img{margin-left: 80px;}
would work if this was just one image but since you have two I would either surround the logo with a div (My preference)

```
<div id="logo></div>

#logo{margin-left: 80px;}
```

OR

add to the logo id you already have

```
#logo{margin-left: 80px;}
```